# How do I stop KDE from dimming the screen while mplayer is fullscreen?

Tags: linux, power-management, kde, fullscreen, mplayer

Whenever KDE (I think) detects no mouse or keyboard activity for a while, it dims my laptop screen, then turns it off. I don't want that when I'm watching a movie.

Is there a setting somewhere to disable this behaviour based on running applications?

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you're using KDE4, you can try a command line call similar to the one's used [here](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=107&t=80118)

*From JanGerrit*

```
Select allqdbus org.kde.powerdevil /modules/powerdevil setProfile <Profilename>
```

> Replace  with the name of a preconfigured profile you added (I think there's something like this called "Presentation" or something similar)

And or

*From Gen2ly*

> Came across today that dbus has an inhibit command i can use. Not the same thing but looks like powerdevil doesn't have the ability to disable power management.

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.PowerManagement /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement \
org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit.Inhibit
```

Comment: So far I've tried `$ qdbus org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement Inhibit MPlayer muuu` ...it doesn't seem to have worked. It does look like I'm on the right path though.

Answer (score 1):

Since KDE 4.5 (or 4.6), functions have changed. Now use

```
qdbus org.kde.kded /org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement loadProfile <ProfileName>
```